# Can't reach this page took too long to respond. Django, Gunicorn and Nginx. This is until I reboot my instance manually

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-lightsail

I hosted my Django website on AWS Lightsail instance on an Ubuntu server with Nginx and Gunicorn.

Everything works fine when it is running super fast everything works great, but sometimes it stops running, I can't reach the website only until I restart my lightsail instance manually.
This I think happens in the interval of 24 hours (probably).

I don't know why it is happening? what causing it?

Someone suggested to me that it's something related to the server itself, Server goes to sleep, or something but when any request comes it can't respond to that.

If there is anything that you want to see to get more info plz comment I'll add that.
I don't have much idea about this problem, I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: I faced the same with FastAPI. don't know what's wrong with lightsail

Answer (score 0):

Its because the server is being overloaded at times this is happening, upgrade to a higher lightsail instance and it will work fine (I had faced the same issue )